# How to copy some part of winedt log output?

Tags: winedt, logging

Winedt shows console output in the lower section of the window. I would like to copy a certain portion of it (say, to paste it as a google search string in my browser). How do I do that? I can select a whole line at a time (it would be better to be able to select a piece of text, but never mind), but cannot copy this line, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> does not work (Windows 10, Winedt 10.3).

Comment: I can select single words, I can also copy&paste both with ctrl+c and with the context menu. If it doesn't work for you you perhaps contact the winedt support. Beside this you could also open the log file with ctrl+l, and copy and paste from there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Finally I figured out what's happening: after compiling I can indeed access it and select/copy any chunk of text from there. However what I was always doing is this: I only turned to the log output if there were some errors, in which case I clicked on the `Find Errors...` button (with the magnifying glass+! icon), whereafter it went into the different mode, when I only can select a single line and cannot copy it. And moreover I cannot exit this mode at all! The only way is to recompile again. This I find impractical - if the log is huge and I want to locate an error, then copy